# List files from a folder in a listbox with recent files showing first

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listbox that displays XLSM files from a folder `Archive` and PDFs from a folder called `PDF` in the folder of the main XLSM file, `Main`.

`C:\Main\Archive\`, `C:\Main\PDF\`, the XLSM looking up these items is located in the root folder `C:\Main\`

I would like to display the most recent modified files in descending order.

So if a file was created today, it would show on top followed by the one created yesterday and so on.

The code I have is just the standard AddItem to ListBox1

```
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsm")
Do While MyFile <> ""
    ListBox1.AddItem MyFile
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
```

These files also have names that start with either FSO or PPG followed by the "ticket number" like 1031, company name, job type and simple date.

```
FSO 10333 Co Name Job Type 042220.xlsm
PPG 10332 Co Name Job Type 042120.xlsm
```

That's how the names are displayed in the listbox.  PDFs are the same name.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It could also show from the highest "ticket number" descending from there.

Comment: It may be best to put the folder info in a sheet, split the filename down, sort on this, then put the sorted vals back in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the following:

- Use of `FileSystemObject` to access file properties like: `GetExtensionName`, `DateCreated` and `Name`.
- Use of `Dictionary` object to create a library and store values in memory.
- Use of `ArrayList` object to create a list to store creation timedate values which we then can `Sort` ascending and `Reverse` to create an descending list.
- We can then iterate `ArrayList` to return values from our `Dictionary` and add them to the `ListBox` in order.

---

```
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim arrList As Object: Set arrList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Dim FSO: Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFolder, oFile

Set oFolder = FSO.getfolder(MyFolder)
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If FSO.GetExtensionName(oFile) = "xlsm" Then
        dict(oFile.DateCreated) = oFile.Name
        arrList.Add oFile.DateCreated
    End If
Next

arrList.Sort
arrList.Reverse

For i = 0 To arrList.Count - 1
    ListBox1.AddItem dict(arrList(i))
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

In support of my comment, omething like this will help you get the date from the file name.  You can then use Excel to sort on this.

```
Sub testing()

Debug.Print get_date("FSO 10333 Co Name Job Type 042220.xlsm")

End Sub

Function get_date(strInput As String) As Date

Dim lngLength As Long
Dim lngLastSpace As Long
Dim strEndSection As String

lngLength = Len(strInput)
lngLastSpace = InStrRev(strInput, " ")
strEndSection = Mid(strInput, lngLastSpace)
strEndSection = Trim(Split(strEndSection, ".")(0))   '   The date bit

get_date = DateSerial(Mid(strEndSection, 5, 2), _
                            Mid(strEndSection, 1, 2), _
                            Mid(strEndSection, 3, 2))

End Function
```